# jQuery onload of div inside iframe same origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to trigger a function when a div inside an iframe is loaded ,the div is loaded, not only the iframe because in my case when the iframe is loaded a jquery ajax call is triggered to loaded data inside that div, so I have two steps: 1st step the iframe is loaded (I can trigger a function in this step) , 2nd step div is loaded after the ajax callback (I can not trigger a function in this step).

No problem with same origin policy because the iframe is inside the same website.

Thanks.

Comment: Why cannot you use ajax callback?

Comment: Please see my comment in Julien Grégoire answer (about postMessage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `dispatch` an `event` from your `iFrame` to the `parent` in your `callback` function. `postMessage` can be used for window communication. 
Like this:

In parent window:

```
  window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false)
    function receiveMessage(e){
         //whatever needs to happen
    }
```

In your iFrame:

```
 window.top.postMessage('div loaded', yourDomain)
```

Comment: Actually I would like to listen to the div load from outside of the iframe and not from the inside because I use this iframe in  many pages and even outside of the website (i.e. in other website, not the same origin), so if I use this solution, it can trigger an error in other website (i.e. not the same origin), sorry I should mention that in the question.

Comment: Yes that's what this solution does. Your eventListener is in the outside frame (here the parent window). postMessage works exactly for these situation, meaning the postMessage sends something that won't create an error. If there's a receiving end, and the origin validation is ok, then it'll work, if not, then there's just a message that isn't handled.

Comment: if not the same origin I get this error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided (my domain) does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Comment: I'm guessing your testing in local. You can try with postMessage('div loaded', '*'). The second argument is to specify to which domain you want to send your message. It's to control where you want your message to be accepted, it can be cross-domain. Say you want to send a message but only if it's to example.com domain then you put postMessage('message', 'example.com'). It's to make sure not to send your message to unwanted window. But it's made precisely to circumvent restrictions on cross-domain restrictions. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: FYI: I was testing in local and in another domain as well but I was getting that error because I was using postMessage('div loaded', '/') , after your help: using '*' instead of '/' has solved my problem.